# Get the login of a user that issued a comment on GitHub actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am running a workflow on

```
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
```

I am trying to get the username of the comment's author but the sample below fails:

```
        run: |
          COMMENT_AUTHOR=${{ github.event.issue_comment.user.login }}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I made a test with [this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester71.yml) generating the following [workflow run](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/actions/runs/3355702316) after adding a comment to an ISSUE.

According to the Github context of this event (cf body below) it seems you can get the **username of the comment's author** by using the following Github context values:

- `${{ github.actor }}`
- `${{ github.triggering_actor }}`
- `${{ github.event.comment.user.login }}`

**Github context payload for the ISSUE comment created event:**

*(using the workflow reference shared above)*

```
{
    "token": "***",
    "job": "job1",
    "ref": "refs/heads/main",
    "sha": "07292d692c3b40708984df7e2bb55237e4c99a14",
    "repository": "GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
    "repository_owner": "GuillaumeFalourd",
    "repository_owner_id": "22433243",
    "repositoryUrl": "git://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions.git",
    "run_id": "3355679821",
    "run_number": "1",
    "retention_days": "90",
    "run_attempt": "1",
    "artifact_cache_size_limit": "10",
    "repository_visibility": "public",
    "repository_id": "351877820",
    "actor_id": "22433243",
    "actor": "GuillaumeFalourd",
    "triggering_actor": "GuillaumeFalourd",
    "workflow": "Test 71",
    "head_ref": "",
    "base_ref": "",
    "event_name": "issue_comment",
    "event": {
      "action": "created",
      "comment": {
        "author_association": "OWNER",
        "body": "test",
        "created_at": "2022-10-30T13:38:36Z",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18#issuecomment-1296261344",
        "id": 1296261344,
        "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18",
        "node_id": "IC_kwDOFPk6vM5NQ2Dg",
        "performed_via_github_app": null,
        "reactions": {
          "+1": 0,
          "-1": 0,
          "confused": 0,
          "eyes": 0,
          "heart": 0,
          "hooray": 0,
          "laugh": 0,
          "rocket": 0,
          "total_count": 0,
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/comments/1296261344/reactions"
        },
        "updated_at": "2022-10-30T13:38:36Z",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/comments/1296261344",
        "user": {
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/22433243?v=4",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/events{/privacy}",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/gists{/gist_id}",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd",
          "id": 22433243,
          "login": "GuillaumeFalourd",
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyNDMzMjQz",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/orgs",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/received_events",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/repos",
          "site_admin": false,
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/subscriptions",
          "type": "User",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd"
        }
      },
      "issue": {
        "active_lock_reason": null,
        "assignee": null,
        "assignees": [],
        "author_association": "OWNER",
        "body": "To check github context on ISSUE",
        "closed_at": null,
        "comments": 3,
        "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18/comments",
        "created_at": "2021-07-16T14:41:41Z",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18/events",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18",
        "id": 946356527,
        "labels": [],
        "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18/labels{/name}",
        "locked": false,
        "milestone": null,
        "node_id": "MDU6SXNzdWU5NDYzNTY1Mjc=",
        "number": 18,
        "performed_via_github_app": null,
        "reactions": {
          "+1": 0,
          "-1": 0,
          "confused": 0,
          "eyes": 0,
          "heart": 0,
          "hooray": 0,
          "laugh": 0,
          "rocket": 0,
          "total_count": 0,
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18/reactions"
        },
        "repository_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
        "state": "open",
        "state_reason": null,
        "timeline_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18/timeline",
        "title": "[TEST] Github Context",
        "updated_at": "2022-10-30T13:38:36Z",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/18",
        "user": {
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/22433243?v=4",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/events{/privacy}",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/gists{/gist_id}",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd",
          "id": 22433243,
          "login": "GuillaumeFalourd",
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyNDMzMjQz",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/orgs",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/received_events",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/repos",
          "site_admin": false,
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/subscriptions",
          "type": "User",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd"
        }
      },
      "repository": {
        "allow_forking": true,
        "archive_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/{archive_format}{/ref}",
        "archived": false,
        "assignees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/assignees{/user}",
        "blobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/git/blobs{/sha}",
        "branches_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/branches{/branch}",
        "clone_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions.git",
        "collaborators_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/collaborators{/collaborator}",
        "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/comments{/number}",
        "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/commits{/sha}",
        "compare_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/compare/{base}...{head}",
        "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/contents/{+path}",
        "contributors_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/contributors",
        "created_at": "2021-03-26T18:31:28Z",
        "default_branch": "main",
        "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/deployments",
        "description": "Various proofs of concept examples using Github Actions ",
        "disabled": false,
        "downloads_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/downloads",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/events",
        "fork": false,
        "forks": 34,
        "forks_count": 34,
        "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/forks",
        "full_name": "GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
        "git_commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/git/commits{/sha}",
        "git_refs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/git/refs{/sha}",
        "git_tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/git/tags{/sha}",
        "git_url": "git://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions.git",
        "has_downloads": true,
        "has_issues": true,
        "has_pages": false,
        "has_projects": true,
        "has_wiki": true,
        "homepage": "",
        "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/hooks",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
        "id": 351877820,
        "is_template": false,
        "issue_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/comments{/number}",
        "issue_events_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues/events{/number}",
        "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/issues{/number}",
        "keys_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/keys{/key_id}",
        "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/labels{/name}",
        "language": "Python",
        "languages_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/languages",
        "license": {
          "key": "apache-2.0",
          "name": "Apache License 2.0",
          "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTI=",
          "spdx_id": "Apache-2.0",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/apache-2.0"
        },
        "merges_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/merges",
        "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/milestones{/number}",
        "mirror_url": null,
        "name": "poc-github-actions",
        "node_id": "MDEwOlJlcG9zaXRvcnkzNTE4Nzc4MjA=",
        "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/notifications{?since,all,participating}",
        "open_issues": 7,
        "open_issues_count": 7,
        "owner": {
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/22433243?v=4",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/events{/privacy}",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/gists{/gist_id}",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd",
          "id": 22433243,
          "login": "GuillaumeFalourd",
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyNDMzMjQz",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/orgs",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/received_events",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/repos",
          "site_admin": false,
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/subscriptions",
          "type": "User",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd"
        },
        "private": false,
        "pulls_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/pulls{/number}",
        "pushed_at": "2022-10-30T13:37:51Z",
        "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/releases{/id}",
        "size": 3239,
        "ssh_url": "git@github.com:GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions.git",
        "stargazers_count": 71,
        "stargazers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/stargazers",
        "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/statuses/{sha}",
        "subscribers_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/subscribers",
        "subscription_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/subscription",
        "svn_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
        "tags_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/tags",
        "teams_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/teams",
        "topics": [
          "beginners",
          "examples",
          "github-actions",
          "poc",
          "proof-of-concept",
          "workflows"
        ],
        "trees_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/git/trees{/sha}",
        "updated_at": "2022-10-26T04:39:55Z",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions",
        "visibility": "public",
        "watchers": 71,
        "watchers_count": 71,
        "web_commit_signoff_required": false
      },
      "sender": {
        "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/22433243?v=4",
        "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/events{/privacy}",
        "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/followers",
        "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/following{/other_user}",
        "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/gists{/gist_id}",
        "gravatar_id": "",
        "html_url": "https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd",
        "id": 22433243,
        "login": "GuillaumeFalourd",
        "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjIyNDMzMjQz",
        "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/orgs",
        "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/received_events",
        "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/repos",
        "site_admin": false,
        "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
        "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd/subscriptions",
        "type": "User",
        "url": "https://api.github.com/users/GuillaumeFalourd"
      }
    },
    "server_url": "https://github.com",
    "api_url": "https://api.github.com",
    "graphql_url": "https://api.github.com/graphql",
    "ref_name": "main",
    "ref_protected": false,
    "ref_type": "branch",
    "secret_source": "Actions",
    "workspace": "/home/runner/work/poc-github-actions/poc-github-actions",
    "action": "__run"
}
```